# Modal delete(and confirm)+edit button with multiple fields

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm want to make delete modal popup (modal popup works - not in js fiddle). The thing is I get everytime from getUserDelID the attr user equal to 1 no metter which button I press.

```
$('#deleteUser').on('click', function (event) {
    var otherProp = $('#getUserDelID').attr("user");
    alert(otherProp);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deleteuser.php",
        how to pass: ? delete = otherProp
        data : $('form.deleteuser').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            //do your validation
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#deleteholder").html(msg)

        },
        error: function () {
            $("#deleteholder").html("error")
        }
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle with modal window look : http://jsfiddle.net/r3b3X/

deleteuser.php makes all the other work like display error's.

HJ05 Made also a edit option : http://jsfiddle.net/r3b3X/3/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID (you have **three** elements with the id "getUserDelID"). jQuery just always returns the first one, which is why you're always getting `1`.

Comment: I thought I could do getUserDelID1,2,3 etc but the id count is not specified and increases with the databse. How could this be solved?

Comment: @Cory var currentUserId;
$("#b").click(function() {
    currentUserId = $(this).attr("data-rowid");
}); i tried something like this to capture the value of first button and later get its value for deleting but still it goes value 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HTML specification an ID can only be used on one element. If you want to have multiple elements with the same "name" you would use classes.

In terms of you are trying to achieve you don't want the modals to open automatically, you want your script to open the modal after clicking the button so in the click handler for the buttons you can get the user id from the event data.

I updated your fiddle to take this into account: http://jsfiddle.net/r3b3X/1/

I've updated your html to use classes instead of ids:

```
<button data-user="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round collapsed getUserDelID"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
<button data-user="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round collapsed getUserDelID"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
<button data-user="3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round collapsed getUserDelID"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Delete User" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> UserDeleting</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="deleteholder"></div>
                <div id="msg-loader"></div>
                <form class="deleteuser">
                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">you sure u want delete id <span class="userId"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </form>
                <div style="padding: 10px 15px;background-color: #f5f5f5;border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;">
                    <button id="deleteUser" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" href="#" id="close" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript to:

```
$('.getUserDelID').on('click', function (event) {
    $('.userId').text($(this).data('user'));
    $('#deleteModal').modal();
});

$('#deleteUser').on('click', function (event) {
    var otherProp = $('.userId').text();
    alert(otherProp);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deleteuser.php",
        data: $('form.deleteuser').serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#deleteholder").html(msg)
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#deleteholder").html("error")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Lovely:) do you have an idea how to make a edit button? And how would should the getusertoedit.php look like? If you know how I would rename the topic name so its more complex and people get a 1 in 2 answer. Looking forward reply.

Comment: What you are asking is essentially for a full tutorial for building an application the would most likely comprise of a database, a back-end application and a front end application and this really isn't a forum that kind of write up and would take more than a few minutes to setup. Maybe take a look at some of the tutorials here: http://spyrestudios.com/27-phpmysql-tutorials-for-building-web-applications/ and if you are looking at a complex front end maybe check out some frameworks such as: http://emberjs.com/ or http://knockoutjs.com/ or http://angularjs.org/

Comment: Well u miss understood me little bit. I know how how to get data and insert them to mysql thing is how should it look like with a modal window 


simple data table [button1 preedit- load modal with values] ajax-> getdata.php
modal : all fields edit button -> ajax update.php

Comment: OK, if I understand what you are asking you would have an additional form on the modal that would get populated when the delete button is clicked and then have a similar setup to delete user click handler.

Comment: Is it hard to accomplish? U got a example of the js code only?

Comment: Ok, here is an example using the jsfiddle echo server: http://jsfiddle.net/r3b3X/3/

Comment: Ok so the first ajax ( should be post? or get? ) I don't know how should it get the values from the php file into the ajax call. Got any tut on that? The second ajax is more clear for me.

Comment: check this json encode (getuserdata.php) http://jsfiddle.net/7yKpF/  how to connect it to your script?

Comment: I updated here to show something similar to your php script. http://jsfiddle.net/r3b3X/4/

Comment: Somehow the modal doesn't pops up only the background changes to dark grey like it would like to appear. The delete modal pops up normally.

Comment: The only problem with the fiddle is the last set of braces and parenthesis is reversed you have ")};" and it should be "});" beyond that there isn't much more help I can provide other than to say look in the console for errors and the network panel to make sure the urls are being built correctly.

Comment: Made a topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905180/jquery-and-json-in-a-modal-to-populate-form-fill-fields-on-load thanks for this one.